# Extracting combinations from a numpy array that sum to a desired output

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to return an array, or an index of that, that contains which combinations of members in a numpy array sum to a specific number.

For example if I take this array and want to find all combinations of its members that sum to 7:

```
import numpy as np

example = np.arange(4) + 1

example
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

it would return:

```
somefunction
>>> [[1,2,4], [3,4]]
```

or an index:

```
>>> [[0,1,2], [2,3]]
```

I can imagine an approach using `itertools.combinations`, although I'd like to avoid this because the dataset I'm trying to use this on already has ~30,000 members. It doesn't function fast enough when considering every length of combinations.

Is there a faster way to do this?

edit: For additional information it's not necessary for me to use every combination of the 30,000 members. For instance, I'm summing whole numbers to ~1000, so I would need < 1000 constituents - in my case the ending number of list constituents is probably going to consist of 100-400 constituents.

Comment: Can you sort the array?

Comment: Sounds like a DP coin change problem.

Comment: Edit: actually yes, you can sort this, woopsy

Comment: Also, depending on the contents of your array the number of combinations can be very large. For example, if you have an array of 30k ones, there are ~`1.6e+38` subsets giving a sum of `10`. You can efficiently _count_ the number of combinations with a given sum before attempting to list them all.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace I just looked up that problem. It's neat but is there an advantage to knowing the number of combinations before listing them?

Comment: @trailing_whitespace I feel I should also mention I'm looking to sum numbers to 1000, which gives much less complexity. Although still a lot.

Comment: @Estif I uploaded an answer with more details about what I meant above. It's hard to tell without seeing the contents of your array, but my hunch is that there will be far too many combinations for you to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended comment rather than an answer. Depending on the structure of your data, listing all combinations of elements with a given sum may be unfeasible. However, there is an efficient way to count the number of combinations. Then you may decide whether or not you want to try listing every one.

For example, with 10k random integers between 0 and 10, I found `243905016604941663446994` subsets that sum to 10 - that's a 24 digit number. If you could list a combination every nanosecond, it would take over 7 million years. The number for an array of 30k random integers summing to `1000` should be considerably larger.

Code snippet to count combinations summing to a number.

```
import numpy as np
import sys

example = np.arange(4) + 1
example_target = 7

# assuming all elemenst of arr are positive integers
def count_combs(arr, sum_):
    arr = np.sort(arr)

    sys.setrecursionlimit(100_000)
    state_dict = {}

    def state(i, j):
        if (i, j) in state_dict:
            return state_dict[(i, j)]
        elif j < 0:
            res = 0
        elif j == 0:
            res = 1
        elif i == 0:
            res = 1 if j == arr[i] else 0
        else:
            res = state(i - 1, j - arr[i]) + state(i - 1, j)
        state_dict[(i, j)] = res
        return res

    return state(arr.shape[0] - 1, sum_)


# print(count_combs(example, example_target))
# prints 2

test_big = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10000)
test_target = 10


def test():
    print(count_combs(test_big, test_target))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
    # e.g. 258364297793668558120414
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I don't believe there's any good answer to the question, thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

You could use if you mind `itertools.combinations`:

```
print([x for i in range(1,4) for x in itertools.combinations(example,i) if sum(x)==7])
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4), (1, 2, 4)]
```

Sort it if you want the order you want:

```
print(sorted([x for i in range(1,4) for x in itertools.combinations(example,i) if sum(x)==7]))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

As you say `itertools.combinations` would be slow, but there is really no other way that's efficient other than `itertools.combinations` tho.

Comment: The OP mentioned that his original array has 30k elements. This would try to check every subset, might take a while :)

Comment: Stated this wasn't optimal in the question.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace Well, this is the only efficient one tho :-), recursion would be worse, lol :D

Comment: @Estif same as what i said to trailing-whitespace: *Well, this is the only efficient one tho :-), recursion would be worse, lol :D*

Comment: @U9-Forward I am pretty sure that you could get an asymptotic speedup with dynamic programming; still may be impractical though.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace Am.. well, i don't know :D